# how to check box work in table for every row correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The checkbox does not work for every row correctly why? How can I make it work?

I [put full code here press on this link](https://jsbin.com/xafekuyeni/edit?html,js,output) tried many times but it does not work.

```js
function check(chk) {
  var checkb = document.getElementById(chk);
  if (checkb.checked == true) {
    document.getElementById('textbox').value = "1234567";
    $(".js-example-basic-multiple").prop("disabled", true);
  } else {
    document.getElementById('textbox').value = "0000000";
    $(".js-example-basic-multiple").prop("disabled", false);
    $(".js-example-basic-multiple").val(null).trigger('change');
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] the question to make it clear what you mean by "does not work"; what behavior are you seeing, and what do you want to happen?

Comment: What specifically about it is broken?

Comment: It might have something to do with the reuse of `id`s for each checkbox. In your full _JSBin_ link, every appended checkbox is given the `id` of `chk1`...

Comment: @JasonAller i can not put code here it appear this message"It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." so, i put it in link  https://jsbin.com/xafekuyeni/edit?html,js,output  behaviour i want whenk checked checkbox element disable select2 and appear numbers in textbox but not work as you see for every row... see the full code in link

Comment: no solution????

Answer (score -1):

`var checkb = document.getElementById(chk.id)`

`checkb` is coming back `undefined` because `document.getElementById` looks for an id value. You are passing `chk` which is the whole checkbox tag, attributes and all. `chk.id` gives you the id and ensures `checkb` is defined. You also need to change

```
document.getElementById('textbox').value = "1234567";
document.getElementById('textbox').value = "0000000";
```

to

```
document.getElementById('textbox1').value = "1234567";
document.getElementById('textbox1').value = "0000000";
```

because you set the ids this way with this line

```
var tBody = tBodyTemplate.replace(/textbox/g, 'textbox' + rowCount);
```

This works when you have just 1 row. When you add more, things break. You also need to make the id unique. `chk1` can't be used as an id for each duplicated row. Ids should be unique

```
'<input type="checkbox" id="chk1"  onclick="check(\chk1\)" >'
```

`chk1` should be paired with `textbox1`. 
`chk2` should be paired with `textbox2` and so on